# How to prevent a file from automatically merging when switching branches in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, branch

Let's say I have two branches named `default` and `newfeature`. I have a file called `readme.txt` in both branches. I'm working on the `newfeature` branch and I make a change to readme.txt. If I run `hg up default` without committing the change, Mercurial automatically merges the version of readme.txt in `newfeature` directly into `default`.

How can I change this behavior? What I'm worried about is developers forgetting to commit before they switch branches, thus merging whatever they've been working on.

This is what the process looks like:

```
C:\source\BranchTest\Main>hg branch
Exams

C:\source\BranchTest\Main>hg status
M readme.txt

C:\source\BranchTest\Main>hg up default
merging readme.txt
0 files updated, 1 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved

C:\source\BranchTest\Main>
```

Notice the automatic merge because I didn't commit the change to readme.txt. Mercurial doesn't warn me that this will happen.

Any suggestions?

Comment: At the very least this make me realize merging was occurring because I had uncommitted changes. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `hg up -c` (lower-case 'c').  This will check your working directory before updating.

You can make this the default in your hgrc file.

Comment: But beware of the very similar `hg up -C` which will discard any changes you made to your working directory.

Comment: So darned deceptively simple. Thanks!

Comment: In that case stick to `hg update --check` and `hg update --clean` to remove ambiguity.